# Go back to the exact post page number

Tags: posts, menus, pages, pagination, buttons

I use pagination in my *index.php* and I have many posts per page. Every post have a button to go back to home. The problem is that when I visit a post in a page 5 for example, the button always send me on the first page.

I'm using this: `<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">back</a>`

Is there a simple way to track the post page position, and use it to go back properly?

Comment: A quick hack: `<a href="<?php echo isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : home_url(); ?>">back</a>`

Comment: `javascript:history.back()` is another slightly hacky option, just simulates the browser's Back button

Comment: @IvanShatsky it works! Thank you so much.

Comment: @mozbot js works good locally but it is not functional if I land on the posts from outside of my website.